# Update color programmatically

Tags: android

I draw lines in the Google Map and how can I update the color in the program?

```
map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                   .add(latlngArray)
                   .width(5)
                   .color(Color.CYAN)
                   .geodesic(true));
```

`Color.CYAN` is the line color. Under certain condition, I need to show the line with different colors. How can I change the Color.CYAN with another color on runtime?

Comment: what do you mean update the color? you can use another color that you define in xml if you need a custom color.

Comment: I like to change Color.CYAN with another color.

Comment: then write something else instead of Color.CYAN. I don't understand where you have the problem.

Comment: he just wants to change the existing color on runtime with another color

Comment: No, whenever the condition is changed, I like to draw with a new color. Instead of using only Color.CYAN.

Comment: Yes bofredo, that is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing something like this:

```
map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                   .add(latlngArray)
                   .width(5)
                   .color( Color.parseColor( "#AARRGGBB" ) )
                   .geodesic(true));
```

Where A is alpha, and RGB is your typical red, green, blue color mapping.  Then you can use any string color you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
        mGoogleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .add(latlngArray)
                .width(5)
                .color( getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary) )
                .geodesic(true));
```

It's for working me

Comment: What's new in this answer?

Comment: using resources color @DimaKozhevin